# Wifi not working on X120e

Tags: networking, wireless

Need help diagnosing/resolving wifi networking issue. Wifi doesn't allow me to enable it, appears to be a driver issue. Networking details displayed using the script below:

```
wget -N -t 5 -T 10 http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57264241/wireless_script && chmod +x wireless_script && ./wireless_script
```

Results:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/10638946/

---

Related - https://askubuntu.com/questions/598955/issues-building-driver-for-my-x120e-on-ubuntu